# Class template vector with pop_back function does not work as I intended

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

   vector<int> VectorName;

   VectorName.push_back(2);
   VectorName.push_back(3);

   cout << VectorName[1] << endl;

   VectorName.pop_back();

   cout << VectorName[1] << endl;

}
```

In my understanding, pop_back() is suppose to pop the last index of the vector, and how I expected the compilation to be was to give me an error; however, the output on the console was stated as:

> 3 3

Will someone explain why the compilation of this program is successful?

Thank you.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Undefined behaviour. C++ almost never gives you error messages at run-time, and this error cannot generally be diagnosed at compile-time,

Comment: *Will someone explain why the compilation of this program is successful?* -- Compiling a program successfully only means that the syntax is correct.  It has nothing to do with whether the program will run correctly.

Comment: Try using `VectorName.at(1)` instead of `VectorName[1]` to see what happens.

Comment: @HenriMenke During the run time, I got out_of_range exception, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector<>::operator[]()` does not check the size of the vector, so your code is producing undefined behaviour.

In your specific case, the vector is shrinking in **size** (the number of items in the vector), but not the **capacity** (the size of the underlying array) when you call `pop_back()`. This means that the second `VectorName[1]` is pointing to unused but existing memory. For example, if we edit your example a bit to check the capacity and the size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<int> VectorName;

    VectorName.push_back(2); // |[2]|
    VectorName.push_back(3); // |[2, 3]|

    VectorName.pop_back();   // |[2], 3|

    cout << VectorName.size() << endl;
    cout << VectorName.capacity() << endl;

}
```

The output is:

> 1
>
> 2

You can see a working example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70d5141bdc375b48

As you can see, the size of the vector is correct (1 item), but the call to `VectorName.pop_back()` does not decrease the capacity, so `3` still exists in the vector, but it is inaccessible.

By accessing the second item after calling `VectorName.pop_back()`, you are causing undefined behaviour. In your case, you get `3`, but compiling the application using a different compiler, architecture or machine may cause your application to crash (or worse)!

Using `vector<int>::at()`, instead of `vector<int>::operator[]()` would have thrown an `std::out_of_range` exception, causing your program to crash. This is because the `at()` function checks the size of the vector and throws an exception if you try to access an out-of-bounds location in the vector. That said, don't rely on the `at()` function to check your vector accesses, prefer to check the `size()` of the vector before calling `VectorName[1]`.

For example, by making a minor edit to your code again, we can see what happens when we use the `at()` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<int> VectorName;

    VectorName.push_back(2);
    VectorName.push_back(3);

    cout << VectorName.at(1) << endl;
    VectorName.pop_back();

    cout << VectorName.at(1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> 3
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>
> what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)
>
> bash: line 7:  4793 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out

Live Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8226be85196f54fe

---

One extra thing on "compilation errors". The compiler will not try to check the size of a vector before you access it, so the compiler will happily compile your code without errors or warnings. It is up to you, as the developer, to perform bounds checking on your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it gave me a greater insight.